# No history for rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb

irb works fine, rails console doesnt!

`~/.irbrc`

```sh
require 'irb/ext/save-history'
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 100
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb-save-history"
```

```
> irb
irb(main):002:0> a="test"
=> "test"
irb(main):003:0> exit
```

```
> cat ~/.irb-save-history
a="test"
exit
```

```
> rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 6238
Loading development environment (Rails 6.1.5.1)
[1] pry(main)> b="test"
=> "test"
[2] pry(main)> exit
```

```
> cat ~/.irb-save-history
a="test"
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `pry`, your history will be in `~/.pry_history`.
If that's not the case, you will find all your history in `~/.irb_history`

EDIT: depending on the OS, you could have `~/.irb-history` (dash, not underscore) file too. So the most updated file should be one of these.

Comment: As you can see from my `~/.pryrc` config, the history file is `~/.irb-save-history`, so I do not have either of the files you mention.

Comment: You did not post any `~/.pryrc`, there is only `~/.irbrc`. I have the same config and despite history should be in `.irb-save-history`, i can find my full history in `~/.irb_history`, that's why i was suggesting you to double check for one of those hidden files